# How to grey-out Operators in the Search Menu

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

When a `poll` method fails, the operator won't even appear in the search menu. But I found some built-in operators that are simply **greyed-out**, letting you know they exist and even hotkey them (even though they won't work in this state).

[image]

### How do you grey-out operators in this manner when a certain condition is not met?

PS. This behavior does not seem to be affected by the Developer Extras toggle in the blender preferences.

Comment: I think it is `bl_options = {'REGISTER'}`

Comment: Removing 'REGISTER' only seems to hide it from the Info window, it still shows up and runs normally from the search menu.

Comment: Are you adding the operator to a menu somewhere? I think if it's in a menu, the menu item will be grayed out when poll fails, but the grayed out menu item will still show up in operator search. For a Python example, see "Export > Motion Capture". There's nothing special in the operator definition though.

Comment: Cool, I was able to replicate the greying-out in the Search Menu by appending the operator (with a failed Poll) to another menu like you suggested. If you create an answer I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grayed out items in the operator search correspond to entries in a menu somewhere.

[image: Operator Search for "convert"]

- `object.convert ▸ Convert To` corresponds to the operator itself; this disappears when poll() is false
- `Object ▸ Convert ▸ Mesh, Curve, etc` corresponds to a menu entry (under the Object etc. dropdown); this gets grayed out when poll() is false

So to get the grayed out entry, add your operator to a menu somewhere. Example:

```
import bpy

class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My Operator only works on Cubes"""
    bl_idname = "test_operator.cube"
    bl_label = "My Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and 'Cube' in context.object.name

    def execute(self, context):
        print('it is a cube')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MyOperator.bl_idname, text="My Operator In A Menu")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyOperator)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: Operator Search for "my opera" showing the grayed out menu item]

Comment: Thanks a ton. Note that I need to wait a full day before I can award the bounty since I just made it. Nice to see the fully detailed answer for anyone else that might find this question.